# How can i make my own cloud server and provide services to others without using any pre-build cloud facility

Tags: cloud, iaas

I have searched on net,but it shows to use owncloud services which is not my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Having something "in the cloud" really just means using somebody else's server.

If you want to make your own "cloud" service, you are going back to the old days of building a server PC (or using a hosting service) and then setting up a software stack on it to serve content and services. The acronym LAMP is a typical stack: Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP - but you can substitute your own favourite technologies here. For example, my current favourite is: Linux, Nginx, Postgresql, Django.

Then you create an application to deliver the software service, manage user accounts, take payment, etc.

For example, I could have a "quote of the day as a service", where someone pays a monthly subscription, and they can then use an API to pull funny quotes off my server. And that would be a cloud service :).

Comment: How can i make my own system as a cloud server?

Comment: You install all the above on your own PC, then talk to your ISP to give you a fixed IP address. Then your clients can reach your service through the fixed IP address.